# WCF client working in UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

we have written a  WCF service and client application.

The wcf service is hosted by console application.
Both client and service application run in the same machine.
The communication between the service and client work fine.

Servive Attributes: 
    ConcurrencyMode = Reentrant
    InstanceContextMode = Single

Client Attributes:
    ConcurrencyMode = Multiple

Note: The  UseSynchronizationContext attribute is not used.

Usage:
  The service pings the client application and the client application responds back to the ping.

Query:
While debugging the service and client application in multiple systems, i observed that in few systems the client application always uses main thread to execute, if the main thread is busy the client method is not called until main thread is free.

In some systems the client always users worker thread to execute the method call invoked by service.In this case even if the main thread is busy the client executes its method.

Why in some systems the client application always require main thread to execute and in some systems the same client server runs on the worker thread?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Investigation:
In some systems a message form is shown based on the condition and some systems doesn't show the message form.
Immediately after message form is displayed, we set up wcf communication channel. 
The systems which shows message form respond to the ping using worker thread other systems respond to ping on Main thread.

Then  i created a seperate client appliction, if i use the form.showDialog before channel creaton the client responds on the worker thread always.
else if the Form.ShowDialog is commented the application responds always on Main Thread.
can anyone please explain this?

Comment: What do you mean by worker thread? GUI app has its main thread (also called UI-thread or dispatcher thread). I you are creating your own worker thread somehow (using background worker etc.) - please share your code  (and code with calling service method and ShowDialog)

Comment: by worker thread I mean any thread other than UI thread. No we are not creating any other thread. 
In the test app i am only dong the following(All in UI thread) still i see the behavior:

1. Create object of form 
2. call show dialog.
3. wcf channel creation.

if i comment step 2 then the client call is executed in main thread(UI thread) otherwise in worker thread.